# configuring Jupyter lab password for docker container in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, passwords, jupyter

So this is driving me nuts. I have a Docker file that includes the line:

```
RUN echo "c.NotebookApp.password='sha256:d46497dc111d:<password_hash>'">>/root/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

I build my image and then run the container as part of a docker compose instruction.

if I open a bash terminal in the container I can find the Jupyter_notebook_config.py file with the line added:

```
c.NotebookApp.password='sha256:d46497dc111d:<password_hash>'
```

when I connect to my machine on the correct port I get the Jupyterlab welcome window without the option to log in using a token (which only happens when the config.py file has the password entry in it). This displays the password prompt but when I enter the password, I get 'Invalid credentials'

So it seems Jupyterlab is running, reading the config file which contains my password but just not allowing it . . What am I missing  . .  help !

The password text was generated using the following python code from another thread here:

```
from notebook.auth import passwd
hashed_password = passwd(passphrase='<my_password>', algorithm='sha256')
print(hashed_password)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah me,

So I re-created my password hash and put it back in the Dockerfile as detailed above and suddenly everything works - methinks I may have created the original hash with a character out of place.

All works really nicely now and there is no un-hashed password floating about anywhere on my jupyter server docker setup

Comment: what were you trying to accomplish ? did you want to be able to enter a certain password when logging into the jupyter instance in the browser?